# Batch script to move .txt files recursively and rename them replacing a specific character

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have 3 folders such as the below structure wise. . .

> - /location1
>
>   - /subdirLocation1
>
>     - foo-bar1.txt, foo-bar2.txt, foo-bar3.txt
> - /location2

The `subdirLocation1` folder is a sub-directory of `location1`. The `location1` folder also contains the files `foo-bar1.txt`, `foo-bar2.txt`, `foo-bar3.txt`. However, the `location2` folder is empty.

### Folder Structure Recap

> - location1 > subdirLocation1, foo-bar1.txt, foo-bar2.txt, foo-bar3.txt
> - subdirLocation1 > foo-bar-subdir.txt
> - location2 > (Empty)

I want to move all .txt files from `location1` and its subdirectories to `location2`, and also rename these .txt files by replacing every "-" with "_" so every hyphen character in the file names becomes an underscore character instead.

**I need to achieve this task using a Windows batch script?**

---

Here's what I came up with originally before I added additional logic I came up with using **FOR** loops below that as well near the bottom of my answer.

This however only moves .txt files from `location1` directory and not from its subdirectory. Also renaming only works for `foo-bar1.txt`, `foo-bar2.txt`, `foo-bar3.txt`. It would not work for `foo-bar-subdir.txt`.

```
MOVE "C:\Users\abcde\Desktop\Practice_Folder\batch rename\location1\*.txt" "C:\Users\abcde\Desktop\Practice_Folder\batch rename\location2"  
RENAME "C:\Users\abcde\Desktop\Practice_Folder\batch rename\location2\*-*" ???_????.txt
```

Below is what I have that's working a little better than the above but the hyphen characters are not being replaced with the underscores in the file names

```
CD "C:\Users\abcde\Desktop\Practice_Folder\batch_rename\locatio‌​n1\" 
for /R %%f in (*-*.txt) do call :copyFile %%f 
goto: eof 

:copyFile 
xcopy %1 "C:\Users\abcde\Desktop\Practice_Folder\batch_rename\locatio‌​n2" 
set file=%~nx1 
rename file %str:-=_%
```

Comment: Yes, I have been trying FOR logic. Here is what I have so far: 
CD "C:\Users\abcde\Desktop\Practice_Folder\batch_rename\location1\"  

for /R %%f in (*-*.txt) do call :copyFile %%f  
goto: eof  

:copyFile  
xcopy %1 "C:\Users\abcde\Desktop\Practice_Folder\batch_rename\location2"  
set file=%~nx1  
rename file %str:-=_%

Comment: @Walmart Sorry this is my first time asking question in superuser.com.. I was unable to edit the comment above.. So here is what I wanted to ask:

I have been looking at FOR loop now. I realize I need a recursive version of FOR loop. So something like 

 `for /R %%f in (*-*.txt) do call :copyFile %%f` 

 Then I am going to copy the .txt files instead of moving them using 

 `xcopy %1 "C:\Users\dbasnet\Desktop\Practice_Folder\batch_rename\location2" ` 

 Now I am unable to rename the files (replacing - with _). Could you give me hints about how to do it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **I want to move all .txt files from location1 and its subdirectories to location2, and also rename these .txt files by replacing every "-"
>   with "_".**

Since you're commented back with a ton of Batch work you've put into this, I wanted to share a script with you that should help for how you explain you need this to work.

Please be sure to test and confirm all works as expected on your side with test data before you run against anything critical or production related.

### Script Example

*<sub>You shouldn't need to use the comment out logic but it's there in case you need it</sub>*

```
@ECHO ON

SET Loc1Dir=C:\Users\abcde\Desktop\Practice_Folder\batch_rename\locatio‌​n1
SET Loc2Dir=C:\Users\abcde\Desktop\Practice_Folder\batch_rename\locatio‌​n2

CD /D "%Loc1Dir%" 
FOR /R %%F IN ("*-*.txt") DO CALL :copyFile %%~F %%~NXF
GOTO: EOF 

:copyFile
SET copyfname=%~1
SET fname=%~2 
SET fname=%fname:-=_% 
ECHO F | XCOPY /Y /F "%copyfname%" "%Loc2Dir%\%fname%"
:::XCOPY /Y /F "%copyfname%" "%Loc2Dir%\"
:::REN "%copyfname%" "%fname%"
GOTO :EOF
```

### Screen Shot Clarification

[image]

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)